# How to share the information of logic variable between environment and use?

Tags: frama-c

I'm trying to generate some annotations for functions. I have succeeded in implementing a plugin that achieves this purpose, but the problem that I am facing is that when I run tests on my plugin, an integrity check is executed automatically and I get an error that says:

> Built-in logic variable \subset information is not shared between environment and use

To demonstrate this problem I have written a simplified plugin that will generate an ACSL annotation for a function called `get_x()`.

The code for the simplified plugin is

```ml
open Cil_types
open Cil
module M = Plugin.Register

let my_emitter =
  Emitter.create "Generate function contract" [ Emitter.Funspec ]
    ~correctness:[] ~tuning:[]

let construct_subset_ip e =
  let t = Logic_utils.expr_to_term e in
  let its =
    [ Logic_const.tinteger 1; Logic_const.tinteger 2; Logic_const.tinteger 3 ]
  in
  let li = Cil_const.make_logic_info "\\subset" in
  li.l_tparams <- [ "a" ];
  let s1 = Cil_const.make_logic_var_formal "s1" Linteger in
  let s2 = Cil_const.make_logic_var_formal "s2" Linteger in
  li.l_profile <- [ s1; s2 ];
  let tn1 = Tunion [ t ] in
  let t1 = Logic_const.term tn1 Linteger in
  let tn2 = Tunion its in
  let t2 = Logic_const.term tn2 Linteger in
  let p = Logic_const.papp (li, [], [ t1; t2 ]) in
  Logic_const.new_predicate p

class my_visitor prj =
  object (self)
    inherit Visitor.generic_frama_c_visitor (Visitor_behavior.copy prj)

    method! vglob_aux =
      function
      | GFun (fd, _) -> if fd.svar.vname = "get_x" then DoChildren else JustCopy
      | _ -> JustCopy

    method! vstmt_aux s =
      match s.skind with
      | Return (Some e, _) ->
          let new_kf =
            Option.get self#current_kf
            |> Visitor_behavior.Get.kernel_function self#behavior
          in
          let bhv = Cil.mk_behavior ~name:"my_behavior" () in
          let ip =
            Visitor.visitFramacExpr self#frama_c_plain_copy e
            |> construct_subset_ip
          in
          Queue.add
            (fun () ->
              Annotations.add_requires my_emitter new_kf ~behavior:"my_behavior"
                [ ip ])
            self#get_filling_actions;
          Queue.add
            (fun () -> Annotations.add_behaviors my_emitter new_kf [ bhv ])
            self#get_filling_actions;
          JustCopy
      | _ -> JustCopy
  end

let execute () =
  ignore (File.create_project_from_visitor "ACSL annotated" (new my_visitor))
```

I applied this plugin on the following C module:

```c
/* run.config
OPT: -autoload-plugins -sandbox
*/

int X;

int get_x() {
  return X;
}
```

The output when executing the plugin on the C module is:

```c
/* Generated by Frama-C */
int X;
/*@ behavior my_behavior:
      requires X ∈ {1, 2, 3}; */
int get_x(void)
{
  return X;
}
```

Now, when I run `$ ptest.opt tests\s1\test.c -show` I get

```
...
[kernel] Parsing tests/s1/test.c (with preprocessing)
[kernel] tests/s1/test.c:8: Failure: 
  [AST Integrity Check]
  AST of ACSL annotated
  Built-in logic variable \subset information is not shared between environment and use
[kernel] Current source was: tests/s1/test.c:7
  The full backtrace is:
  Raised at Project.on in file "src/libraries/project/project.ml", line 405, characters 59-66
  Called from File.init_project_from_visitor in file "src/kernel_services/ast_queries/file.ml", line 1818, characters 4-64
  Called from File.create_project_from_visitor in file "src/kernel_services/ast_queries/file.ml", line 1842, characters 2-43
  Called from Sandbox_visitor.execute in file "sandbox_visitor.ml", line 60, characters 9-77
  Called from Stdlib__Queue.iter.iter in file "queue.ml", line 121, characters 6-15
  Called from Boot.play_analysis in file "src/kernel_internals/runtime/boot.ml", line 36, characters 4-20
  Called from Cmdline.play_in_toplevel_one_shot in file "src/kernel_services/cmdline_parameters/cmdline.ml", line 846, characters 2-9
  Called from Cmdline.play_in_toplevel in file "src/kernel_services/cmdline_parameters/cmdline.ml", line 876, characters 18-64
  Called from Cmdline.catch_toplevel_run in file "src/kernel_services/cmdline_parameters/cmdline.ml", line 235, characters 4-8
  
  Frama-C aborted: internal error.
  Please report as 'crash' at https://git.frama-c.com/pub/frama-c/issues
  Your Frama-C version is 24.0 (Chromium).
  Note that a version and a backtrace alone often do not contain enough
  information to understand the bug. Guidelines for reporting bugs are at:
  https://git.frama-c.com/pub/frama-c/-/wikis/Guidelines-for-reporting-bugs
```

What is this error about, and how do I solve it?

---

*PS: Excuse me for any bad coding practices that you might notice. I'm a beginner in both Ocaml and Frama-C.*

Comment: Maybe because you are creating a new variable for `subset` instead of looking for the existing one?

Comment: If your goal is only to emit new annotations (without modifying the AST), I'd suggest to use a visit in-place. If you are afraid of modifying the original AST, you can just create a copy before visiting the copy in place. Adding things to the AST or the annotations during a copy requires to deal with original/future states in the same code which is error prone.

Comment: Sure! In fact I tried to find the existing `subset` but never succeeded in finding it. Do you know in which module I can find it? Thanks! @Anne

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tips about not creating an new project but just visiting in-place. Yes, that is exactly the case, I only want to emit annotations. The reason I copied the project is that I followed the example in chapter 4.17.7 in the [Developer Manual](https://frama-c.com/download/frama-c-plugin-development-guide.pdf) in which the authors copy the project when the purpose is also only emitting annotations. I'll try just visiting in-place. Thanks! @Ksass'Peuk

Comment: You can search in the logic_environment using `Logic_env.find_all_logic_functions`. The function is automatically registered by the kernel in this table since it is a builtin function.